# How to stream only the audio of a song, from the songs Youtube URL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, android-music-player, just-audio

How to stream only the audio of a song, from the song's Youtube URL in flutter?

I tried downloading the audio file of the song from the Youtube URL and playing it. Instead of downloading it, I need to stream it online. Is there any way to do this in flutter?